# Can a property such as First Color be set using code?

Tags: android, dynamic, properties, basic4android

Can a property such as First Color be set using code?

I would like to do something like this:

```
btnMyButton.drawable = "StatelistDrawable"
btnMyButton.drawable.EnabledDrawable = "GradientDrawable"
btnMyButton.drawable.EnabledDrawable.firstcolor = "255, 199, 199"
btnMyButton.drawable.EnabledDrawable.secondcolor = "255, 79, 79"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need to create a `GradientDrawable` as below:

`GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            new int[] {0xFFRRGGBB,0xFFRRGGBB});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);`

Where `RRGGBB` is the color code in hex (eg `99CC00`)

And then set the drawable as the background of your button:

`btnMyButton.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);`

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. I will try it later. Do you know if Basic4Android has a decimal to Hex function I can use? Something like decToHex(99CC00)

Comment: Ah I didn't realise you were using the Basic4Android framework, the sample code above may not work unless you can include snippets of Android SDK Java code in your application. As for converting between decimals and hex, [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/DecimalToHexadecimal.shtml) page should help. Apologies if my code isn't useful.

Comment: Don't worry. I will see if it works anyway most likely tomorrow and will let you know what happens. Thanks.

Comment: I think I need to wait until my skills have developed with Basic4Android to see how to embed java into the coding. Thanks for trying anyway. :-)

Comment: You cannot directly embed Java into Basic4android code. You can however compile it into a custom library and reference that.

Comment: Thanks agraham, When I get further into the "Getting Started" manual I'm hoping there is a tutorial on how to do that.